# Shorter way to return date of last wednesday

Tags: python, python-datetime

I would like to return the date of last wednesday using Python. However, if today is a wednesday, then it still should return the date of last week's wednesday and not today's date.
Right now, I use the following code:

```
today = date.today()

if today.weekday() == 2:
    last_wednesday = today - timedelta(weeks=1)
else:
    last_wednesday = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday()) + timedelta(days=2)

return last_wednesday
```

Since I come from Java, I'm used to a much shorter way:
`return LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY));`

So, my question is: Is there a similiar method to achieve this with just one line in Python, too?

EDIT: To clarify my question, the function should not return the date of last week's wednesday, but the date of the "latest" wednesday. So, that is, what I want:

```
2021-03-22 (Monday) --> 2021-03-17 (Last week's wednesday)
2021-03-23 (Tuesday) --> 2021-03-17 (Last week's wednesday)
2021-03-24 (Wednesday) --> 2021-03-17 (Last week's wednesday)
2021-03-25 (Thursday) --> 2021-03-24 (This week's wednesday)
2021-03-26 (Friday) --> 2021-03-24 (This week's wednesday)
```

Comment: Can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you, in terms of `today.weekday()`, the number of days it has been since last Wednesday? I think you will find this is really more of a math question than a programming question.

Comment: Look at the module `dateutil`. That has very capable class called `relativedelta` that might be closer to what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
def last_wednesday(date):
    return date - datetime.timedelta((4 + date.weekday())%7 + 1)
```

This will return the previous Wednesday on any date, and never the date itself.

Comment: OP wants it to return the previous Wednesday (i.e., use a `timedelta` of `7`) on Wednesday, by my reading.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You are right. Fixed it now

Comment: Thanks, but see the update in my question for clarification purposes!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly less complex than @mousetail

```
day - timedelta(days=5 + day.weekday())
```

Test function..

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
for x in range(-4, 4):
    day = today + timedelta(days=x)
    print(day, day - timedelta(days=5 + day.weekday()))
```

```
2021-03-20 2021-03-10
2021-03-21 2021-03-10
2021-03-22 2021-03-17
2021-03-23 2021-03-17
2021-03-24 2021-03-17
2021-03-25 2021-03-17
2021-03-26 2021-03-17
2021-03-27 2021-03-17
```

Comment: Thanks, but see the update in my question for clarification purposes!

Comment: @XDAF, that's the price of not writing your question clearly.  You can easily derive the answer from what has been written above.